# JSch Compare local file to remote file

Tags: java, jsch

I need to compare a local file to a remote file for differences. Currently, I have it checking for modified time and size difference, however, this would not cover differences withing the file.

Current code:

```
for (String dm : remoteMods) {
    Long remoteTime = (long) sftpChannel.stat(pack + "/" + dm).getMTime() * 1000;
    Long localTime = new File(minecraftInst + dm).lastModified();
    Long remoteSize = sftpChannel.stat(pack + "/" + dm).getSize();
    Long localSize = new File(minecraftInst + dm).length();

    if (remoteTime.longValue() != localTime.longValue() || remoteSize.longValue() != localSize.longValue()) {
        System.out.println("Downloading: " + minecraftInst + dm);
        sftpChannel.get(pack + "/" + dm, minecraftInst + dm);
        new File(minecraftInst + dm).setLastModified(remoteTime);
    }
}
```

This works great for zip files, however, it doesn't work well with text files.

Comment: please explain `This works great for zip files, however, it doesn't work well with text files. `

Comment: Have you considered getting a hash (MD5, SHA, whatever) of the contents of both files and then comparing them?

Comment: @ScaryWombat I am comparing both zip files and text files.

Comment: are you saying that text files do not store the modified datetime?

Comment: @dschulz I like this idea, however, I am unsure how to go about doing it. I am currently looking at how to send the "md5sum" command to the server and reading the output, is there a better way than this?

Comment: @dschulz This won't work as the server I am connecting to only allows sftp, therefore SSH commands will not work.

Comment: @ScaryWombat of course the store the time, but the local files change all the time, where as the remote files change seldom. This is because some of the files get reread upon running and rewritten. That leaves an updated modification time but not actual modification.